# How can I remove links from the function "get term list"?

Tags: taxonomy, terms

```
<?php echo get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'people', 'People: ', ' ', '' ); ?>
```

returns something like this:

```
People: <a href="person1">Person1</a>, <a href="person2">Person2</a>, ...
```

How can I make it return the same thing without links like this:

```
People: Person1, Person2
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It may be easier to just write the list manually, something like:

```
<?php
$terms = wp_get_post_tags( $post->ID );
//For custom taxonomy use this line below
//$terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, 'people' );

foreach( $terms as $term )
    $term_names[] = $term->name;

echo implode( ', ', $term_names );
```

Comment: How would this work for a custom taxonomy? I tried: 
`$terms = get_the_term_list( $post->ID,'people');` but that gave me an error

Comment: @Carson you are using the wrong function there, you want `wp_get_object_terms()` so it would be: `$terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, 'people' );`

Answer (score 13):

Alternatively you can also use

```
<?php 
echo strip_tags (
    get_the_term_list( get_the_ID(), 'tax_name', "Text Before Value ",", " )
);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I found another method that more directly answers my question:

```
<?php $terms_as_text = get_the_term_list( $post->ID,'people', 'People: ', ', ');
if (!empty($terms_as_text)) echo '<p>', strip_tags($terms_as_text) ,'</p>'; ?>
```

Credit:  [CSS Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/forums/discussion/11225/display-wordpress-custom-taxonomy-tags-but-not-as-links/p1)

Comment: don't do that. use Joe's solution, but with [`wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'people')`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_terms) instead of wp_get_post_tags()

Answer (score 1):

Using strip_tags() Can get complicated if you want to show your terms as an HTML list.
Here, there's something for you. $raw set to true (or anything that's not empty) will just create an inline list with the $separator of your choice, if not, it will generate an HTML list without links. If you want your list to have a styled title, set the $titletag to, say H1 or H2. If you don't want a title, just leave $title empty.

```
function show_tax($taxname, $title, $title_tag, $raw, $separator){
    $terms = get_the_terms($post->ID, $taxname);
    $out = '';
    if (!empty($title)){
        if(empty($title_tag)){
            $title_tag = 'span';
           }
            $out .= '<'.$title_tag.'>'.$title.'</'.$title_tag.'>';
        }
    if (!empty($raw)){
                $out = implode($separator, $terms);
        }
        else{

            $out .= '<ul>';
                foreach ( $terms as $term ){
                            $out .='<li>'.$term->name.'</li> ';
                            }
                $out .= '</ul>';

        }       
            return $out;
}
```

Example of use:

```
echo show_tax('people', 'PEOPLE', 'h3', '', ''); // An html list with PEOPLE as title
echo show_tax('people', 'PEOPLE:', '', true, ','); // An inline list with PEOPLE: as before text
```

Comment: updated code. `implode` didn't work cause it is an array of post objects